# Getting "timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000" with chrome browser 105

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting error after clicking on a element, though element is clicked correctly, will get below error
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 120.000
(Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
Using below options,
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-component-update");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-automation");

```
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            chromeOptions.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT_AND_NOTIFY);
            chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
```

Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests already have waits in them, you can probably use:

```java
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
```

which means that the web page will no longer try waiting for all scripts to load (which were never fully loading).

That could lead to flaky tests because now you might not be waiting long enough for certain elements, but handling that scenario is easier.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was using chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE); only, but using this giving other problems like selenium not waiting for page load and getting  "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found”. for any of the dynamic waits.

Comment: In Python there is ``WebDriverWait`` and ``expected_conditions``. Perhaps Java has something similar to let you wait specifically for what you need to wait for.

Comment: I had added similar dynamic waits in java also but getting InvalidArgumentException for waits.

Comment: The ``InvalidArgumentException`` means you have a typo in your script somewhere.

Comment: Nope, no issues with arguments. Because same script works fine when i give some pause and execute.